# Adding optional route for Laravel 5.8 nested category set

Tags: php, laravel

I am using [Laravel-nestedset](https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset) for my categories and I am trying to add an optional route for a category that is more than one level deep.  I am not sure if the Laravel-nestedset package is irrelevant in what I am trying to do or has everything to do with it.  When I add the extra `{category?}` to the end of my route, I get an error that `category` can't be called more than once.  I am also using [Laravel-sluggable](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sluggable) and was wondering if I needed to pass the slug as the second optional parameter, but then I would probably lose the benefit of the `show` action.

**web.php**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'categories', 'as' => 'categories.'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'CategoryController@index')->name('categories');
    Route::get('/{category}/{category?}', 'CategoryController@show')->name('show');
});
```

**// Update**

I added the extra route and nav link as a test.

**web.php**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'categories', 'as' => 'categories.'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'CategoryController@index')->name('categories');
    Route::get('/{category}', 'CategoryController@show')->name('show');
    Route::get('/{category}/{slug?}', 'CategoryController@show')->name('showsub');
});
```

**nav.blade.php**

```
...
<li>
    <a href="{{ route('categories.showsub',['category'=>'carnival-games', 'slug'=>'large-scale-games']) }}">
        <div>Large Scale Carnival Games</div>
    </a>
</li>
...
```

Although the url changed to `http://carnival-experts.test/categories/carnival-games/large-scale-games` without error, the template still displays the content from `http://carnival-experts.test/categories/carnival-games` page.

Answer (score 1):

The question mark makes `slug` optional, so you don't need two different show routes.  The following will handle both `/{category}` and `/{category}/{slug}` just fine.

**web.php**

```php
Route::get('/{category}/{slug?}', 'CategoryController@show')->name('show');
```

But you do need to accept the `slug` parameter in your controller if you want to receive it as a variable. You have not included your controller code, so it's impossible to say if you have done this.  By setting the default value `$slug = null`, you can safely pass one or both variables.  Then you can alter the page output accordingly.

**CategoryController.php**

```php
public function show($category, $slug = null)
{
    if (!is_null($slug)) {
        // show subcategory (slug) page
    } else {
        // show category page
    }
}
```